# Unable to access a web-service from a C++ client when using WSE

Tags: c++, web-services, wse

I am trying to access a .net webservice(built in vs 2008) from a c++ application. I am using IXMLHttpRequest to access the service.Following is the code for that:

```
 MSXML::IXMLHttpRequestPtr httpReq( _uuidof(MyXMLHTTPRequest));
_bstr_t  HTTPMethod ;
_variant_t noAsync = _variant_t( (bool)false );

HTTPMethod = _bstr_t( "POST" );    
httpReq->open(HTTPMethod ,"webservice address",noAsync);   
httpReq->setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml");

CString szRequest;
szRequest = "SOAP string";   

VARIANT vRequest;
vRequest.vt = VT_BSTR;
vRequest.bstrVal = szRequest.AllocSysString();

httpReq->send(vRequest);
BSTR strText;

_bstr_t bsResponse = httpReq->responseText;
```

But I am getting a soap exception when I add the following line in web.config file. Why is that happening and What is the solution? How can I access the service which is using WSE?

```
   <webServices>
  <soapExtensionTypes>
    <add type="Microsoft.Web.Services2.WebServicesExtension, Microsoft.Web.Services2, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxx"/>
  </soapExtensionTypes>
</webServices>
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
<soap:Fault>
<faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faultstring>System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderException: Server unavailable, please try later ---&gt; System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()
at System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)
at System.Web.HttpResponse.End()
at  Microsoft.Web.Services2.WebServicesExtension.BeforeDeserializeServer(SoapServerMessage message)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---</faultstring><faultactor>http: //localhost:2211/WebSite/WebServices/JobLogService.asmx</faultactor></soap:Fault>
```

Answer (score 0):

> SoapHeaderException: Server unavailable, please try later

isn't this the problem? Perhaps the issue is the web service is not starting when ou moduify the web.config.

Comment: I know that. I am asking why is that happening? what is the solution?